# Translation of verses from Matsya Purana

Tags: translation-request

Requesting a translation of the following verses 34-36 to English, from the Matsya Purana, Chapter 3:

> ततो वसिष्ठप्रमुखा भगिनीमिति चुकृशुः।
> ब्रह्मा न किंचिद् ददृशे तन्मुखालोकनादृते॥३४॥
>
> अहो रुपमहो रूपमिति प्राह पुनः पुनः।
> तत: प्रणामनम्रां तां पुनरेवाभ्यलोकयत्॥३५॥
>
> अथ प्रदक्षिणं चक्रे सा पितुर्वरवर्णिनी।
> पुत्रेभ्यो लज्जितस्यास्य तद्रुपालोकनेच्छया॥३६॥

Comment: Based on my meagre knowledge: then the ones headed by Vasishtha ¿chakrishu? their sister. Brahma did not seen anything except her face and eyes. 34. Brahma again and again said, “Oh what Form! Oh what form!”. ¿He bowed to her and saw her again? 35.. she then circumambulated her father (who was ashamed by his sons) with a desire to see his form. 36..

Comment: Adding to what @Archit has translated, "Vasishtha and his brothers exclaimed (Chakrshuh) "That's our sister!"". I guess this is the description of the wooing of Sarasvati by Brahma.